# Create dynamic length check on view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a dynamic length check in my index view. The index view is dynamic and shows different input fields based on the data. Now I want to have a length check on some of these input fields, so that I can give some parameters in an object and send that to my index page, read it out and create a listener to check if the user didn't filled in too much characters.

If the user typed to much in the textbox I want to show immediately that the user entered to much in the text field.

What is the best way to create a length check on text fields on a page, 
with sending the id's of the text fields in an object to the index page.

Comment: Show your current View. I suppose you should use `DataAnnotaion` attribute `[Length(...)]` on your ViewModel fields, but can't say anything particular unless you show code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keydown event, and then check the length of the input field

in the example below, I'm verifying when the length is 5 to add a hyphen:

```
var cep = document.getElementById('cep');
cep.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
   var code = e.keyCode || e.charCode || e.which;

   if(cep.value.length === 5 && code !== 0 && code !== 8){
       cep.value+='-';
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But this is when you know which inputfield will be used. I would like to create a dynamic view (View 'A' contains inputfield 'cep' and 'pec', and view 'B' contains 'ara' and 'aba' as inputfields). What is the best way to create a view like that?